# Vertical Navbar- can somebody explain why the first one is working and the second not?

Tags: html, css

My Question:

How is it possible to do it without classes and ID? I don't understand why one works and the other does not. I thought in css you would only work with classes and id. Is it possible to describe other objects in css without id or class?

The first one:

This worked in the test.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The second:

This one created a bad site.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


#li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

#li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="ul">
  <li><a id="li a" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="li a" href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a id="li a" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a id="li a" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In 2nd example, you added id in `a` tag instead of `li`

Comment: the problem is that you use an ID "li a" which is not an ID. ID strings have always be together and no spacing. Also an ID needs to be unique. In you case its no unique, you should have used classes instead Of course you can work in CSS withotu ID or classes but can style all tags in general. ID and classes are needed if you want to define specific elements. But be aware that ID's needs to be unique!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Example without class

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

In 2nd example, you added id in `a` tag instead of `li`, just change it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


#li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

#li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="ul">
  <li id="li"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li id="li"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li id="li"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li id="li"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second version would work if you set `id="li"` on the `<li>` element and remove the `id="li a"` from the `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same `id` for different tags use a `class` or change the `id` name. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` takes the width of the text whereas `display: block` takes whole width of the parent. Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}


#ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

#li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="ul">
  <li><a id="li a" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="li a" href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a id="li a" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a id="li a" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on how your answer actually addresses the question.